# Updating the value of BehaviorRelay property

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

When I try to set a value, I have an error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property

```swift
var value: BehaviorRelay<Any?>

var unpackedValue: Any? {
    get {
        return value.value
    }

    set {
        value.value  = newValue // error
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information on this ```BehaviorRelay<Any?>``` as there seems to be the issue with the ```value```. Where did you get it from. Is there an import needed? My XCode and Swift cannot find it.

Comment: @Simon `BehaviorRelay` is a property from RxSwift library

Answer (score 3):

on `BehaviorRelay` properies you need to use `accept(_ event: Element)` to send a new value

```swift
var unpackedValue: Any? {
    get {
        return value.value
    }
    set {
       value.accept(newValue)
    }
}
```

Refer to the implementation of [BehaviorRelay](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxRelay/BehaviorRelay.swift)

> Accepts `event` and emits it to subscribers

Comment: Also, the BehaviorRelay should not be a `var`. You should be declaring it as a `let`. For example `let value = BehaviorRelay<Any?>(value: nil)`